# Magento2.2.2 Add Customer Attribute

Tags: magento, module, magento2, magento2.2

How can I add a Customer Attribute within a module to the Register and edit page?

And how could I replace `0,00€` with `Free`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create customer attribute to follow step in given URL:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html